CPU-bound code blocks main thread with faststream and fastapi
I have a zip file with csv tables which are read and formatted with polars. I want to run it so this operation doesn't block my main thread. But it blocks it and fastapi cannot process any incoming requests while dataframes are being formatted.
I have my fastapi endpoint which user sends zip file to. Zip file goes to S3 storage.
And I have my faststream queue which gets this zip file from S3, unzips it and processes csv files with polars.
Fastapi endpoint
@router.post("/upload",)
@inject
async def upload_file(
    file: UploadFile,
    file_processing_service: FileProcessingService = Depends(
        Provide[Container.file_processing_service]
    ),
    authrozied: dict = Depends(role_checker),
    user_data: dict = Depends(verify_token)
    
):
    file_id = str(uuid4())
    zip_file = ZipFile(content=BytesIO(file.file.read()), filename=file.filename, id=file_id)
    zip_file.filename =  translit(zip_file.filename, "ru", reversed=True)
    file_processing_service.save_zip_file(zip_file)
    connection_id = user_data.get("sid")
    await brocker().publish({"zip_id": file_id, "client_id":connection_id}, "file_preparing_queue")
    return "File recieved"

Fastsream queue
router = RabbitRouter(RabbitMQSettings().get_url())


def brocker() -> RabbitBroker:
    return router.broker


active_connections: Dict[str, WebSocket] = {}


@router.subscriber("file_preparing_queue")
@inject
async def file_preparing_queue(
    zip_id_and_client: dict,
    file_processing_service: FileProcessingService = Depends(
        Provide[Container.file_processing_service]
    ),
):
    zip_file = file_processing_service.get_zip_file(zip_id_and_client.get("zip_id"))
    dataset = file_processing_service.process_zip_file(zip_file)
    parquet_buffer = convert_to_parquet(dataset)
    parquet_file = ParquetFile(
        content=parquet_buffer,
        id=zip_file.id,
        filename=zip_file.filename.replace(".zip", ".parquet"),
    )
    client_id = zip_id_and_client.get("client_id")
    dataset_metadata = DatasetMetadata(
        id=zip_file.id,
        state="loaded",
        not_validated_messages=[],
        filename=parquet_file.filename,
        user_id=client_id,
    )
    dataset_metadata = DatasetMetadata.model_validate(dataset_metadata)
    file_processing_service.save_as_parquet(parquet_file)
    file_processing_service.add_dataset_metadata(dataset_metadata)
    try:
        await manager.send_message(
            client_id, {"message": "Preparing finished"}
        )
    except Exception as e:
        module_logging.error("Error sending validation response", e)
    await router.broker.publish({"dataset_id": zip_file.id, "connection_id": client_id}, "validation_queue")

